# INSERT INTO a table variable in T-SQL with value contains backslash

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query:

```
DECLARE @Test NVARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE @t AS TABLE (name NVARCHAR(30))

INSERT @t (name)
VALUES  ( '\\
    \
    \\
     \b
     \c' )

SELECT * 
FROM @t
```

Why is the output I get:

```
 \\ \b   \c
```

not same as what I had in the input?

How this issue can be resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Back slash with Line feed causing the issue.
please refer the details given on below link, this may help you.
[MS SQL Backslash preceding new line/line feed removes line break](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10900330/ms-sql-backslash-preceding-new-line-line-feed-removes-line-break)

Answer (score 0):

If you are checking the results as a grid, then you're not going to see any difference.

You should switch your output to text instead - in the menu **Query** -> **Results to** -> **Results to Text**, or simply hit `Ctrl+T`.

This way you should see the results as you have them entered in the input.

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/5ff77/1) is also working SQLFiddle demo.

Let me know if this still is not helpful.

Comment: Your demo represents the problem they are asking about and provides a workaround, the output of the two SQL is not the same. So the first three sentences of this answer don't make sense in that context. You seem to be saying it is an issue with the grid output when your demo shows it isnt.

Comment: @MartinSmith Yes, I can see that. It looks like if I select 'Plaintext output' in SQLFiddle, it is not saved with the URL.